# WordPress post filter odity

Tags: wordpress, filter

I'm trying to develop a WordPress custom post type filter, concerning rentable spaces, which need to be filtered on location and both price and square meters (area) or in any combination. Now, the filter works properly for pricing, but does not do so for space of the area, as no results keep showing up, with one exception.

When I try to filter for spaces between 1-100 nothing shows up, but dare I select between 20 and 30, a space with 29 (only one between said values) does show. The area is stored as an integer, as is price.

The fields used in the filter are location (dropdown), min-price, max-price, min-area and max-area (all number input fields).

What's it I oversee?

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post_type' => 'spaces',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'rental_status',
            'value' => 'available',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    )
);
$args['meta_query'] = array();
if (isset($_POST['location_filter']) && $_POST['location_filter'] || isset($_POST['min_area']) && $_POST['min_area'] || isset($_POST['max_area']) && $_POST['max_area'] || isset($_POST['min_price']) && $_POST['min_price']  || isset($_POST['max_price']) && $_POST['max_price'])
    $args['meta_query'] = array('relation' => 'AND');
if (isset($_POST['min_area']) && $_POST['min_area'] && isset($_POST['max_area']) && $_POST['max_area']) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'area',
        'value' => array($_POST['min_area'], $_POST['max_area']),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'between'
    );
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['min_area']) && $_POST['min_area'])
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'area',
            'value' => $_POST['min_area'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>'
        );
    if (isset($_POST['max_area']) && $_POST['max_area'])
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'area',
            'value' => $_POST['max_area'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<'
        );
}
if (isset($_POST['min_price']) && $_POST['min_price'] && isset($_POST['max_price']) && $_POST['max_price']) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'total_fee',
        'value' => array($_POST['min_price'], $_POST['max_price']),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'between'
    );
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['min_price']) && $_POST['min_price'])
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'total_fee',
            'value' => array($_POST['min_price'], 10000),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'between'
        );
    if (isset($_POST['max_price']) && $_POST['max_price'])
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'total_fee',
            'value' => array(1, $_POST['max_price']),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'between'
        );
}
if (isset($_POST['location_filter']) && $_POST['location_filter']) {
    $args['meta_query'][] =  array(
        'key' => 'location',
        'value' => $_POST['location_filter'],
        'compare' => '='
    );
}
```

Comment: I would suggest dumping (print_r) `$args['meta_query']` to the screen so you can see the final output of the query builder. That may perhaps help. I suspect there is something about the data from the form that could be unexpected - my simple tests in your code do seem to work so I am questioning the input values and the final output based on those.

Comment: Thanks! I checked that - of course. But oddly the data inputs are practically the same, only having a different name.. I checked them to a database level and even there they are exactly the same.

Comment: In addition, when I combine the area with the location_filter, or the price the results DO in fact show. Wheras price also works with no other filters.